# Qual a melhor forma de exibir uma classificação de itens sem sobrecarregar o sistema?

Tags: php, mysql

Olá

O site que atualmente estou trabalhando foi desenvolvido utilizando Laravel, tendo como banco de dados o MYSQL. A base atualmente tem 500 mil jogadores cadastrados. Cada jogador tem uma pontuação. Atualmente o sistema mostra os 50 melhores, então eu faço uma consulta no banco pegando apenas os 50 primeiros melhores resultados. Quando um perfil é acessado, se ele está entre os 50 é exibido sua classificação, caso contrário não aparece a classificação.

Mas agora o sistema tem de ser modificado e está sendo exigido que mostre a posição de cada um dos 500 mil jogadores em seus respectivos perfis.
Porém, acho extremamente desgastante para o sistema ter de pesquisar em uma tabela com 500 mil resultados milhares de vezes ao dia.

Nesse caso, pergunto a vocês. Qual a melhor forma de exibir esses dados sem sobrecarregar o sistema? É viável exibir uma classificação em uma base grande?

Comment: 500 mil é muita coisa, não? Melhor manter os 50 e caso não esteja entre os 50, fazer uma consulta pelo nome do jogador pra ver qual a classificação dele

Comment: Se for fazer uma paginação de 100 por página, daria 5 mil páginas... acho inviável

Comment: Como é o esquema das tabelas desse sistema? Já trabalhei com grande quantidade de dados e uma solução que achei foi usar os `indexes` do MYSQL. Assim as consultas, mesmo sendo grandes, são melhores filtradas e não vai sobrecarregar tanto o banco.